# How to create a new Sitecore Analytics report to show assets download per contact

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, reporting

I'm trying to create a custom report on sitecore analytics to display Assets downloaded per contact.

Currently there is a report to show downloaded assets but it doesn't display who has downloaded those assets.

I saw the following post on sitecore community forum, where a person had achieved this same functionality. But, he hasn't given much information on how he achieved that.
https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/9/t/8384

Any help/guidance in the correct path would be really helpful.

Version: Sitecore 8.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be able to insert new fields into the analytics index, you should have the following:

1. Custom Crawler
2. Index Aggregator
3. Pipeline

The crawler inherits from the `ObserverCrawler<T>` type. The generics type identifies the kind of `IIndexable` object the crawler handles. For example, one of the crawler handles visit objects and another crawler handles contact objects.

```
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Crawlers;
using Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Models;

public class AnalyticsDownloadCrawler : AnalyticsObserverCrawler<DownloadEventIndexable>
{
}
```

The implementation of the `DownloadEventIndexable`

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Sitecore.Abstractions;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Args;
using Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Pipelines;

public class DownloadEventIndexable : AbstractIndexable
{
    public DownloadEventIndexable(PageEventData eventData, string url, Guid interactionId, Guid contactId)
    {
        var str = interactionId + url + eventData.DataKey;
        this.Id = (IndexableId<string>)str;
        this.UniqueId = new IndexableUniqueId<Guid, string>(contactId, $"downloadEvent|{str}");
        this.DataSource = "sitecore_aggregation";
        this.AbsolutePath = string.Empty;
        this.Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(ContentSearchManager.SearchConfiguration.AnalyticsDefaultLanguage);
        this.LoadFields(eventData, url, interactionId, contactId);
    }

    public override void LoadAllFields()
    {
    }

    private void LoadFields(PageEventData eventData, string url, Guid interactionId, Guid contactId)
    {
        this.Fields = DownloadEventIndexableLoadFieldsPipeline.Run(ContentSearchManager.Locator.GetInstance<ICorePipeline>(), new DownloadEventIndexableLoadFieldsPipelineArgs(eventData, url, interactionId, contactId));
    }
}
```

You need to implement a pipeline which will load the fields and add it to the index. Define the arguments for the pipeline first as shown below.

```
using System;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Pipelines;

public class DownloadEventIndexableLoadFieldsPipelineArgs : IndexableLoadFieldsPipelineArgs
{
    public DownloadEventIndexableLoadFieldsPipelineArgs(PageEventData eventData, string url, Guid interactionId, Guid contactId)
    {
        this.EventData = eventData;
        this.Url = url;
        this.InteractionId = interactionId;
        this.ContactId = contactId;
    }

    public PageEventData EventData { get; private set; }

    public string Url { get; private set; }

    public Guid InteractionId { get; private set; }

    public Guid ContactId { get; private set; }
}
```

Once you have implemented the arguments, create the pipeline which will trigger the `loadfields`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Sitecore.Abstractions;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Args;

public class DownloadEventIndexableLoadFieldsPipeline
{
    public static List<IIndexableDataField> Run(ICorePipeline pipeline, DownloadEventIndexableLoadFieldsPipelineArgs args, string pipelineName = "downloadeventindexable.loadfields")
    {
        try
        {
            pipeline.Run(pipelineName, args);
        }
        catch
        {
            ObservationLog.Log.Debug(() => "Could not resolve pipeline - " + pipelineName);
        }
        return args.Fields;
    }
}
```

This is the pipeline which will add the data to the index fields. If you want to change or add new fields, this is where it should be done.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Args;

public class DownloadLoadFields : DownloadIndexableLoadFieldsProcessor
{
    protected override IEnumerable<IIndexableDataField> GetFields(DownloadEventIndexableLoadFieldsPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

        PageEventData eventData = args.EventData;

        Assert.IsNotNull(eventData, "eventData");

        List<IIndexableDataField> indexableDataFieldList = new List<IIndexableDataField>()
        {
            new IndexableDataField<Guid>("visit.InteractionId", args.InteractionId),
            new IndexableDataField<Guid>("contact.Id", args.ContactId),
            new IndexableDataField<string>("contact.download", args.EventData.ItemId.ToString()),
            new IndexableDataField<string>("type", "assetdownloadevent")
        };

        return indexableDataFieldList;
    }
}
```

You need to implement the processor so that when the pipeline runs, it can resolve it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Args;

public abstract class DownloadIndexableLoadFieldsProcessor
{
    public virtual void Process(DownloadEventIndexableLoadFieldsPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (args == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args));
        args.Fields.AddRange(this.GetFields(args));
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<IIndexableDataField> GetFields(DownloadEventIndexableLoadFieldsPipelineArgs args);
}
```

You need to have the aggregator which will create a new DownloadEventIndexable object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.Pipeline;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Model;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Extensions;
using Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Models;

public class AnalyticsDownloadEventAggregator : ObservableAggregator<DownloadEventIndexable>
{
    public AnalyticsDownloadEventAggregator(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<DownloadEventIndexable> ResolveIndexables(AggregationPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Context.Contact == null)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<DownloadEventIndexable>();
        }

        if (!args.Context.Contact.ShouldBeIndexed())
        {
            ContentSearch.Diagnostics.ObservationLog.Log.Debug(() => $"The visit page events will not be indexed because contact {args.Context.Contact.Id} does not have an identifier and the system is not configured to index anonymous contacts and their interactions.");

            return Enumerable.Empty<DownloadEventIndexable>();
        }

        List<PageData> pages = args.Context.Visit.Pages;

        Func<PageData, PageEventData, DownloadEventIndexable> resultSelector = (page, @event) => new DownloadEventIndexable(@event, page.Url.ToString(), args.Context.Visit.InteractionId, args.Context.Contact.Id.Guid);

        return pages.SelectMany(page => page.PageEvents, resultSelector);
    }
}
```

Once the code implementation has been done, you need to patch the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Analytics.config` and `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config`

**Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <group groupName="analytics.aggregation">
        <pipelines>
          <interactions>            
            <!-- Custom Download Aggregator -->
            <processor type="Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Aggregators.AnalyticsDownloadEventAggregator, Sitecore.Extension.Analytics">
              <param desc="name">DownloadAggregationObservable</param>
            </processor>
            <!-- END Custom Download Aggregator -->         
          </interactions>          
        </pipelines>
      </group>    
      <downloadeventindexable.loadfields>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Pipelines.DownloadLoadFields, Sitecore.Extension.Analytics" />
      </downloadeventindexable.loadfields>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Analytics.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="sitecore_analytics_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <!-- Custom Download Crawler -->
              <crawler type="Sitecore.Extension.Analytics.Indexes.AnalyticsDownloadCrawler, Sitecore.Extension.Analytics">
                <CrawlerName>Lucene Download Crawler</CrawlerName>
                <ObservableName>DownloadAggregationObservable</ObservableName>
                <NumberOfSecondsToQueue>60</NumberOfSecondsToQueue>
                <MinimumQueueSize>500</MinimumQueueSize>
                <MaximumQueueSize>50000</MaximumQueueSize>
                <ThrottlingEnabled>False</ThrottlingEnabled>
              </crawler>
              <!-- END Custom Download Crawler -->

            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Below is a screenshot of the values in the sitecore analytics index.

[image]

Here is the list of dlls I have referenced in my solution

1. Sitecore.Analytics.dll
2. Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.dll
3. Sitecore.Analytics.Model.dll
4. Sitecore.kernel.dll
5. Sitecore.Abstractions.dll

**Note**

- The `Sitecore.Extension.Analytics` namespace is a custom from the solution where I implemented the code.
- I am using Lucene for the Sitecore Analytics index.
- I have not implemented the Analytics dashboard.
- You can find more information from my blogpost [here](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2018/06/06/sitecore-add-my-stuff-to-analytics-index/)